Can I say "I'm so inclined to.." to mean that "I want to do something so badly"?
I wonder why it's difficult for me to find an example of "so inclined to" in the affirmative form. On the other hand, I've come across many in the negative form, for example:

I'm not so inclined to go to Dave's party.

So, do you say "I'm so inclined to..." meaning that "you want to do something so badly". If not, could you suggest some common alternatives to the latter?

Fyi, so is anaphoric: Pers. 1: Do you really believe that? Pers. 2: Yes, I so inclined. (I agree with the answers below.) It refers back to that.

Oops. I'm so inclined.

In very formal language "much inclined" was used, today this will sound pompous or simply stuffy to modern ears. To learners of English I would not recommend imitating this style or level of formality.

I am much inclined to think that the King must be vested with a larger share of Power than he has at present, or it will be very difficult if not impossible to restore Peace and good order, without much bloodshed.
The Papers of Thomas Jefferson, Volume 17: July 1790 to November 1790


Yes, he is very willing: this blessing of the people, it is a work whereunto he is much inclined, and wherein he is most delighted.
The Works of the Rev. William Bridge (1845)

The following excerpt is more recent, but uses the compound "nobody" which has a negative sense.

To tackle its housing and transport problems effectively, though, the valley probably needs a regional government of sorts. During the Internet boom, nobody was much inclined to think about these issues.
The Economist (2002)


Typically "inclined" implies a slight or moderate preference, so it doesn't make sense to use it with an intensifier. Although it can be used as an understatement to imply a stronger preference.

No, we don't say "I am so inclined to..." to mean that you very much want to do something. We would use a different word such as "keen" or "desperate", for example

I am keen to go to Dave's party.

The word 'inclined' is used in a situation where you aren't very sure about something, but on balance decide one way or the other. The usage is similar to 'leaning', for example

I am inclined to believe that story.
I am leaning towards John's version.


The fragment I’m so inclined to… has a contradictory tone. On the one hand, as you suggest, so indicates that the speaker’s desire is intense. But on the other hand, implicit in the meaning of be inclined to is a certain mildness or weakness:

Are you going to the party?
Welll… I guess I’m sort of inclined to, but I don’t know. Maybe I’ll stay home and read a book.

